# Im trying to update a users information using MongoDB and JWT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jwt

when I use this code to try and update the user it appears as a server error. Im using JWT and mongodb but am unsure if im pulling the token or the id to update the users information. Below my controller code is attached and my schema.

```
const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    
          try {
           
            const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id)
            if(!user) return res.status(400).send({ error: 'User not found'})
            Object.assign(user, req.body);
            user.save()
            res.send({ data: user})
        
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({error: 'Server Error'})
          }
      }


const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Updated update function but i appear to have an error

```
 const updateUser = async (req, res) => {

      try {
       
       const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body)
       if(!updatedUser) return res.status(400).send('User cannot be updated!')
       res.json(updatedUser)
    
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({error: 'Server Error'})
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please comment if more code is needed to execute this action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//update user by id
exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
        const updatedUser = await 
<--req.params.id is the user.id and req.body contains the requested fields to update -->
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req.body) 
            res.json(updatedUser);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at edited code.  I submitted the request in thunder-client and received my custom error. how can i fix this?

Comment: Never mind, the error is fixed. Thank you.